# IntelliJ IDEA shows error for matHeaderRowDef

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-material, angular-directive

IntelliJ Idea 2020.1 shows this error for `matHeaderRowDef` in a template:

```
Property matHeaderRowDef is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template
```

[image]

[GitHub example](https://github.com/tmtron/idea-ng-material-table) to reproduce the issue

I don't understand why this error is shown:

- The `DemoMaterialModule` in [material.module.ts](https://github.com/tmtron/idea-ng-material-table/blob/master/src/app/material-module.ts) exports the `MatTableModule` where [MatHederRowDef](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatHeaderRowDef) is defined.
- Other structural directives from `MatTableModule` show now error: e.g. [MatHederCellDef](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatHeaderCellDef) works fine
- note: the application works fine when you start it - so maybe it's just an issue in the IDE

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45270. It will be resolved in 2020.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug in IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45270) and is fixed in Version 2020.1.2